# Developing DOS program using DosBox as test bed and windows/linux as developing platform

Tags: c, windows, emulation, dos, dosbox

I want to write some program for MSDOS machine and want to use DosBox as my testbed. I was wondering if its possible to use windows tools like eclipse or visual studio or some other tool as an IDE and then compile and execute it in DOSBox without manually copying files to DOSbox mounted drive and then manually compiling and running. I have Turbo C and Microsoft C compiler for DOS. I am also open to use any virtual machine like Qemu, Virtual Box etc which allows me to do same.

Comment: Can't you just specify the directory that you're mounting in DOSBox as the output directory for whatever compiler you're using?

Comment: Write the command-line inputs for compiling (the file name of the compiler and the command line arguments) the file into a batch file. Save the batch file in the directory of the files. Drag and drop the batch file to the desktop icon of DOSBox. DOSBox will automatically mount the directory which contains your batch file and the batch file will automatically start.